# Getting and Converting Binary Image Data to Uint8ClampedArray

Tags: reactjs, next.js, line, binary-data, uint8array

I am developing a LINE bot to use to receive data and picture to be save in database and later use in website.

The picture that my bot will mainly receive will be coupon with QR-code. So, this is the result I got when I receive picture from LINE in the form of Binary image data.

Result:
[image: Binary image data result]

and this is my code when I retrieve my picture from line's message and detect the type of message.
From api/line.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
const request = require('request')
require('dotenv').config()

let count = 0

const cal_state = []

let calState = false

const line = require('@line/bot-sdk');

export default function test(req, res) {


    // handle LINE BOT webhook verification
    // The verification message does not contain any event, so length is zero.
    if (req.body.events.length === 0) {
        res.status(200).json({})
        // console.log("hello")
        reply("Hello")   // can reply anything
        return
    }

    let event = req.body.events[0];

    let reply_token = event.replyToken


    let id = event.source.userId


    if (event.message.type !== 'text') {

        let arr = []

        const client = new line.Client({
            channelAccessToken: process.env.CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN
        });
    
        client.getMessageContent(event.message.id)
            .then((stream) => {
                stream.on('data', (chunk,p) => {
                    arr.push(chunk)
                    console.log(chunk)
                });
                stream.on('error', (err) => {
                    console.log("Error", err)
                });
            });

        reply(reply_token, event.message.type)
        console.log("arr: ",arr)


    } else {
        postToDialogflow(req)
    }
}

function reply(reply_token, msg) {


    let headers = {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer {' + process.env.CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN + '}'
    }

    // console.log('msg:', msg)
    let body = JSON.stringify({
        replyToken: reply_token,
        messages: [{
            type: 'text',
            text: msg
        }]
    })
    console.log("reply =============> ", body)

    request.post({
        url: 'https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/reply',
        headers: headers,
        body: body
    }, (err, res, body) => {
        // console.log('status = ' + res.statusCode);

        // console.log("body ====> ", res.body)
    });
}
```

I can normally `console.log(chuck)`. But, when I try to store it in some variable. For example, in arrays. It say that `chuck` is not defined.

Error:
[image: Store Error]

Furthermore, is there a way to convert binary image data into Uint8ClampedArray object. Since the npm library that I use to decode the QR-code from picture is this one. https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsqr

And it require to pass imageData as Uint8ClampedArray object.

This is my code when I process QR-code from picture (as of right now It get `image.src` from static image in the folder). And the below code is in the separate file. I plan to put this code into api/line.js

QR-Reader Code(from index.js):

```
import Head from 'next/head'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
import jsQR from 'jsqr'
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export default function Home() {

  const [qrData, setQRdata] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    
    const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const image = new Image;
    let imageDataT = new Uint8ClampedArray()
    image.src = './img/Coupon_with_Hash.png'
    image.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      imageDataT = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, image.width, image.height);
      console.log(imageDataT);
      const code = jsQR(imageDataT.data, image.width, image.height, 'dontInvert')
      if (code) {
        setQRdata(code.data)
        console.log("Found QR code", code);
        console.log("Result", code.data);
      } else {
        console.log("Do not detect code.")
      }
    }
  })

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main className={styles.main}>
        <h1 className={styles.title}>
          Detect QR-Code from Picture
        </h1>

        <p className={styles.description}>
          Static Image show from folder 'public'.
        </p>

        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>

        <p>Result: {qrData}</p>
      </main>

      <footer className={styles.footer}>
        
      </footer>
    </div>
  )
}
```

How to do I store the result from line and convert the binary image data to Uint8ClampedArray object?

Comment: For the first part, "chuk" is different than "chu**n**k"

Comment: For the second part, where does this data come from exactly? What kind of data is it? Are these the chunks of an encoded image file (e.g png)?

Comment: For the second part, this chuck come from an encode image file that I call from LINE by using 'event.message.id' as the point reference to get the image from the message that user send. @Kaiido

Comment: And for the first part, I correct my misspell. But the chucks did not go in the empty array. I have edited my question on that part. @Kaiido

Comment: You are pushing asynchronously in your array, you need to wait for the streaming ends before logging it. And for the second part, could you link to the documentation of that API?

Comment: Message API. Look for image: https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#message-event

I add the code from this part. https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/#get-content

https://developers.line.biz/en/reference/messaging-api/